# sql return most prevalent column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm a beginner at SQL, how do I get a query which returns the most prevalent column value? Probably there is an answer somewhere but I don't know how to google it.

For example in the user_id column the query should return the value 1 because this is the most prevalent number.

[image]

Comment: Users prefer text based tables instead of images.

Comment: What's the expected result in case of a tie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to do a `GROUP BY` aggregation and then apply a `LIMIT` trick:

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

If you want something more complex, then you would be getting into the realm of rank functionality.  MySQL (at least as of the current release) does not support built-in rank support, so it can be tricky to perform such queries.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT top 1 user_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't support `TOP`, that is SQL Server syntax.

Comment: That won't execute on MySQL.

Comment: @jarlh It makes me wonder where I actually got all my points :-(

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, ha ha, don't worry, I'm sure most of them are well deserved.

Comment: I had read SQL in the question and because of that I response with SQL syntax instead of MySQL syntax.

My bad guys

Comment: @DanielPaiva, that's not SQL. That is tsql.

Answer (score 1):

Have a common table expression that counts each user_id. Select user_id where the count is the max count. Will return both user_id's in case of a tie.

```
with cte as
(
    SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY user_id
)
select user_id
from cte
where cnt = (select max(cnt) from cte)
```